# passing data to jquery and ajax paginating

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

So, I'm trying to do ajax pagination with laravel, there is dropdown, which searches through categories and displays them and that works but the pagination is the problem, i want to pass the type and page to url to make it dynamic but the pagination is not even responding, can you please take a look at the code ?

pasing data using data filters

```
<div id="filterUrl" data-url="{{ route('admin_scat_test') }}" data-id='3'></div>
    <select name="citylist" id="filterType" form="carform" onchange="loadCategory(this.value)">

      @foreach($scattegories as $key=>$category)
        <option value="{{ $key }}" data-id="{{ $key }}">{{ $category }}</option>
      @endforeach

    </select>

    <div id="txtHint"><b></b></div>
```

trying to paginate things

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function () {
        page = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');
        getProducts(page);
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.pagination a', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var page = $(this).attr('href').split('page=')[1];
        location.hash = page;
    });
    function getProducts(page) {
        var url = $("#filterUrl").data("url");
        var type = $("#filterType").data("id");
        console.log(type);
        $.ajax({
            url: url + '?type=' + type + '&page=' + page
        }).done(function (data) {
            $('#txtHint').html(data);
        });
    }
```